# getting this java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-edittext

This function giving some error of String input, I am new, that's why I don't find the solution. I Solved it**

```
public  void  editBtn(){
    btn33.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // count = 0;
            // loopCount.setText("0"); // when click to the edit loop will be Zero
           try {
                String no = btn33.getText().toString();
                String no2 = tvTotal.getText().toString();
                tv33.setText(no);
                int a = Integer.parseInt(no);
                int b = Integer.parseInt(no2);
                int result;
                result = b / a;
                count = result;
                loopCount.setText(String.valueOf(result));


            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is where I want to implement division method, Like when btn33(edit Text) takes input it will divide with tvCount. tvCount has predefined value
How to do that? I added my screenshot and log Cat.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nri4m.jpg)

log Cat

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.green.muslim.myapp, PID: 8597
java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
at com.green.muslim.app.tasbih.fragments.TasbihFragment$2.onClick(TasbihFragment.java:74)
```

Comment: Check the value of b it definitely going to be zero on parsing

Comment: thanks @AnkitTale